# How to sort an array in a very specific order in PHP

Tags: php, sorting

Let's say I'm trying to sort an array called $off that looks like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => alistair
            [id] => 344
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => barney
            [id] => 333
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => carlos
            [id] => 100
        )
```

I want to sort it so that it is always in this order: "carlos, alistair, barney" and that if the name is not in the ordering, it will not be in the array. I know I have to use usort but I have no idea how to do a cmp. I'm using a sub php5 version too so I can't use an anonymous function. What is the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$arr = array(
    array('name' => 'alistair', 'id' => 344),
    array('name' => 'barney', 'id' => 333),
    array('name' => 'carlos', 'id' => 100),
);

$order = array(1 => 'carlos', 'alistair', 'barney');

usort($arr, function($a, $b) use($order) {
    $a_index = array_search($a['name'], $order);
    if (!$a_index) {
        $a_index = 999;
    }

    $b_index = array_search($b['name'], $order);
    if (!$b_index) {
        $b_index = 999;
    }

    return $a_index - $b_index;
});

var_dump($arr);
```

The same in php4 friendly way:

```
$arr = array(
    array('name' => 'alistair', 'id' => 344),
    array('name' => 'barney', 'id' => 333),
    array('name' => 'carlos', 'id' => 100),
);

usort($arr, 'sorting_function');

function sorting_function($a, $b)
{
    $order = array(1 => 'carlos', 'alistair', 'barney');

    $a_index = array_search($a['name'], $order);
    if (!$a_index) {
        $a_index = 999;
    }

    $b_index = array_search($b['name'], $order);
    if (!$b_index) {
        $b_index = 999;
    }

    return $a_index - $b_index;
}

var_dump($arr);
```

Comment: I get a "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION" error here. I'm using php4 is that the problem?

Comment: @pg.: yes it is. Create a separate function and move the `$order` declaration to its body. The anonymous functions were introduced in php 5.3

Comment: maybe this is a separate question but the "order" has to be gotten from a mysql call. Is there a way to import data into a cmp function? I don't know how usort uses it.

Comment: @pg.: create a function that returns the order, like `$order = get_me_the_order();` and implement it in any way you like